# Не отображается компонент вложенного маршрута, Vue-Router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Настраиваю маршрутизацию, используя VueRouter, VueJS. Компонент LessonsList отображается, url меняется.router-link работает. Но не отображается вложенный компонент - Lesson. Вместо него компонент 404 ошибки. Страница не найдена. Маршрут при этом такой, каким и должен быть.

Что я делаю не так?

routes.js

```
const LessonsList = () => import ('./components/Course/LessonsList');
const Lesson     = () => import ('./components/Course/Lesson');
const E404       = () => import ('./components/Store/E404');

const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        redirect: {name: 'course'}
    },
    {
        name: 'course',
        path: '/course',
        component: LessonsList,
        children: [
            { name: 'lesson', path: 'lesson:id', component: Lesson }
        ]
    },
    {
        path: '*',
        component: E404
    }
];
```

LessonsList.vue

```
<template>
    <ul>
        <router-link v-for="(lesson,index) in lessons"
                     v-bind:key="index"
                     v-bind:to="'/course' + /lesson/ + lesson.id"
                     tag="li">

            <h2>LessonsList</h2>
        </router-link>
    </ul>
</template>
```

Lesson.vue

```
<template>
    <section>
        <h4>Lesson</h4>
  </section>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Используя Vue Router, необходимо учитывать следующее:

> Функциональный компонент `<router-view>` отображает компонент, соответствующий данному маршруту. Компоненты внутри `<router-view>` также могут содержать в шаблоне собственный `<router-view>` (он будет использован для отображения компонентов вложенных маршрутов).

т.е. в вашем случае в главном компоненте (приложении):

```
<router-view></router-view>
```

и в компоненте `LessonsList.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h2>Lessons</h2>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="(lesson,index) in lessons" :key="index">
        <router-link
          :to="{
            name: 'lesson',
            params: {
              id: lesson.id
            }
          }"
          tag="a"
        >{{ lesson.title }}</router-link>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
// 1. Определяем компоненты для маршрутов.
// Они могут быть импортированы из других файлов
const LessonsList = Vue.component('LessonsList', {
  data() {
    return {
      lessons: [{
          id: 1,
          title: "Lesson 1"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          title: "Lesson 2"
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          title: "Lesson 3"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  template: `
  <div>
    <div>
      Lessons
      <router-link to="/lessonslist">Перейти к lessonslist</router-link>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="(lesson,index) in lessons" :key="index">
        <router-link
          :to="{
            name: 'lesson',
            params: {
              id: lesson.id
            }
          }"
          tag="a"
        >{{ lesson.title }}</router-link>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
  `
})
const Lesson = Vue.component('Lesson', {
  template: `
  <section>
    <h4>Lesson {{ $route.params.id }}</h4>
  </section>
  `
})
const E404 = Vue.component('E404', {
  template: `
  <section>
    <h4>Error component</h4>
  </section>
  `
})

// 2. Определяем несколько маршрутов
const routes = [{
    path: '/',
    redirect: {
      name: 'lessonslist'
    }
  },
  {
    name: 'lessonslist',
    path: '/lessonslist',
    component: LessonsList,
    children: [{
      name: 'lesson',
      path: 'lesson:id',
      component: Lesson
    }]
  },
  {
    path: '*',
    component: E404
  }
]

// 3. Создаём экземпляр маршрутизатора и передаём маршруты в опции `routes`
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes // сокращённая запись для `routes: routes`
})

// 4. Создаём и монтируем корневой экземпляр приложения.
const app = new Vue({
  router
}).$mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router@2.8.0/dist/vue-router.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  Демонстрация Vue Router | текущий url - {{ $route.path }}
  <hr>
  <!-- отображаем тут компонент, для которого совпадает маршрут -->
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

Всю необходимую информацию вы можете получить из [официального руководства Vue Router](https://router.vuejs.org/ru/)